# React Native Router for iOS and Android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I am writing an App for Android and iOS. I am a real noob to JavaScript/React native etc. and i hope my question isn´t to nooby...

I tried to implement a LoginPage with two Buttons on the Main View and a StatusBar icon for informations which links me, for example, to an Impressum Page/View. This works great with the [react-native-router](https://github.com/t4t5/react-native-router) module on iOS. My index.ios.js looks like this:

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (
        <Router firstRoute={firstRoute}
                headerStyle={styles.statusBar}
                titleStyle={styles.title}
                backButtonComponent={BackButtonIcon}
                rightCorner={ImpressumIcon}
        />
    );
}
```

ImpressumIcon.js for the icon which links to the ImpressumPage

```
var ImpressumIcon = React.createClass({

goToImpressumPage: function () {
    this.props.toRoute({
        name: 'Impressum',
        component: ImpressumPage,
    });
},

render() {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="transparent" onPress={this.goToImpressumPage}>
            <Image source={require('image!infoicon')} style={styles.icon}/>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    )
}

})
```

Like mentioned this works great for iOS. Now trying to do the same will give me an exception - **null is not an object (evaluating 'StatusBarIOS.setStyle')**

Now i traced the error and it brought me to the libraries - node_modules-libraries-Components-StatusBar - Here are two classes. StatusBarIOS.ios.js and StatusBarIOS.android.js. The android one just returns null. So now i am trying to figure out what to do next.
Should i try to implement the bindings by myself or is there a easier way to solve my problem? Maybe somebody has a hint for me what to do next.

I saw the Navigator Component in the React Native API, but unfortunately this gave me the same error...

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a React Native Login example that uses a WebView to login to your existing backend. Check this out and see if it solves your issue: https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/react-native-login

Answer (score 0):

It is because of react-native-router component - best solution is to delete all related lines of codes from /node_modules/react-native-router/index.js file